# Post to facebook group with C# code

Tags: c#, facebook, post

I am working on a windows application where I embedded webbroswercontrol. I am trying to post sample message to a open facebook group. I am unable to change value of a textbox with c#.     When ever I automate click it says textbox value is null. What would be the fix?

---

```
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" class="mentionsHidden" 
                                 name="xhpc_message" value="lklklkl">
```

---

```
HtmlElement textBox = this.FindControlByName("xhpc_message", 
                                              this.webBrowser.Document.All);

//Click Code
var elements = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
    // If there's more than one button, you can check the
    //element.InnerHTML to see if it's the one you want


    if (element.InnerText.Contains("Post"))
    {
        if (textBox.InnerText.Trim() == "Write something...")
        {
            textBox.Focus();
            textBox.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Test Message");
            IHTMLElement nativeElement = element.DomElement as IHTMLElement;
            nativeElement.click();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Comment the textbox code and try passing hard coded string values. Meanwhile I'll try to get the workaround...

Answer (score 2):

1) I suggest you to ensure, that textbox is null, not the textBox.InnerText. Usually inner text for  elements is null, so its better to check the "placeholder" attribute and update the code with:

```
// if (textBox.InnerText.Trim() == "Write something...")
if (textBox.GetAttribute("placeholder") == "Write something...")
```

2) This code doesn't set the value. It gets the value and compares to "Test message".

```
textBox.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Test Message");
```

Just use SetValue instead.

```
textBox.SetAttribute("value", "Test message");
```

3) Ensure, that all operations are made after page is loaded.

```
public SomeFormName()
{
    ...
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
}

void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    // put your code here
}
```

4) Not sure, how the FindControlByName is working, so check a simple LINQ query to ensure that textbox is found.

```
var textbox = webBrowser.Document.All.OfType<HtmlElement>()
    .Where(item => item.Name == "xhpc_message")
    .FirstOrDefault()
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below after the Document complete event has been fired completely in a separate function, after commenting your code.The URL in the webbrowser should be holding the Group Page on which the post is to happen.

```
private void AfteDocumentLoads()
    {
        HtmlElementCollection textBox = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea").GetElementsByName("xhpc_message");
        HtmlElementCollection button = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in textBox)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement btnelement in button)
            {
                if (btnelement.InnerText == "Post")
                {
                    element.Focus();
                    element.InnerText = txtPortalUserId.Text.ToString();
                    btnelement.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was also stuck as it was not posting earlier because I was using WebBrowser class to get current WebBrowser. Result was that the text was inputted to the Group as a 'dim' Comment. Even if I clicked manually on FB page it would say "This status update appears to be blank. Please write something or attach a link or photo to update your status."

I used the page's webbrowser & it worked cos' it came in proper manner on the page. Also little bit of changes are there in the LOCs

Comment: you can use   `element.SetAttribute("Value",string);` instead of ` element.InnerText`

Comment: @Chandana, I used a Button to call the function, you can later on automate it if U want.